# Error in plotting xts object: 'x' must be a time-series object

Tags: r, plot, error-handling, time-series, xts

dataframe "Bangladesh" looked like-

```
  Province  Country      Cases  Date
1  NA       Bangladesh     0    2020-01-22
2  NA       Bangladesh     1    2020-01-23
3  NA       Bangladesh     2    2020-01-24
4  NA       Bangladesh     3    2020-01-25
```

To convert to xts i used the following code

```
Bangladesh_xts <- xts( Bangladesh, order.by= Bangladesh$Date)
Bangladesh_Final <- Bangladesh_xts[,-4]

           Province  Country      Cases
2020-01-22  NA       Bangladesh     0
2020-01-23  NA       Bangladesh     1
2020-01-24  NA       Bangladesh     2
2020-01-25  NA       Bangladesh     3
```

is.xts (Bangladesh_Final) shows "TRUE".
But when I am trying

`plot(Bangladesh_Final$Cases)`
This message is shown every time "Error in plot.xts(Bangladesh_Final$Cases) : 'x' must be a time-series object". What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to select the `Cases` to avoid changing the class from numeric to `character` as `xts` is also a `matrix` and `matrix` can have only a single class

```
Bangladesh_xts <- xts( Bangladesh$Cases, order.by= as.Date(Bangladesh$Date))
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I guess i have to use ggplot if i want to keep the other columns.

Comment: @AfridaShama Yes, you may use the original object `Bangladesh` for ggplot or perhaps `autoplot` or may be convert to `tsibble`